# Add content for particular users based on profile variables modified by User admin

Tags: drupal

I have a role, called User Admin. User Admins administer registered users. I want the User Admin to be able to tick a box so that particular users see additional blocks on particular pages. Is the best practice way to do that to add a variable to a user profile, and then use Context to check that variable and display the block if it is set/true?

How I do add a variable to a user profile without the user themselves being able to modify it, but only the User Admin?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that exactly the sort of things that [Organic Groups](https://drupal.org/project/og) should be able to handle?

Comment: I don't think that is what I need. I'm actually thinking of using https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions to add fields to a profile that the user themselves cannot modify.